# How can I integrate BinderHub on my own Website?

Tags: python, data-science, jupyter

I hope you guys are familiar with jovial.ml.
jovial.ml lets us fire up jupyter notebooks just like Kaggle. Jovial uses binder hub for this.

I want to know, how can I do the same on my own website. Launch my own jupyter notebooks on my website.

I have added the screenshot of a notebook from jovial.ml

[Jovial.ml screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adUis.png)

Comment: so what is jovial.ml?

Comment: Hey, Jovial teaches Data Science online. You can check them out on jovial.ml